# Consuming web service with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, get

I am trying to run the code below but nothing happens.

I do not receive any error messages on Firefox/Chrome in developer options.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    var AltCoin = "ripple";
    //var api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + AltCoin;
    var api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: api_url,
        data: AltCoin,
        success: function(data) {
            try {                                   
                $('#coin_value').html(data);
            }
            catch (error) {
                alert('error found');                                
            }
        }
    });
});

<article class="article">
    <h1>Ripple</h1>
    <p id="coin_value">test</p>
    <p></p>
    <p><strong></strong></p>
</article>
```

The script is very basic.

Comment: If you add an `error` handler you can see the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/whw29h0g/

Comment: As per your code i seen Api Returns Some Data in json Format sir [https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ripple/](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ripple/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the API you're calling returns data in JSON format, not JSONP. They aren't interchangeable.

To fix the problem, change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`. Try this:

```js
var AltCoin = "ripple";
var api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: AltCoin,
  url: api_url,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //$('#coin_value').html(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="article">
  <h1>Ripple</h1>
  <p id="coin_value">test</p>
  <p></p>
  <p><strong></strong></p>
</article>
```

You will need to loop through the resulting object in your `success` handler and append the data in the required format.

Also note that if you call `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ripple` - as you seem to intend, yet the code is not doing - then you will be blocked by CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Sir please try this i think its helpful for you

```js
var AltCoin = "ripple";
var api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/";

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: AltCoin,
  url: api_url,
  success: function(data) {
  var content="";
 
  $.each(data[0], function(key, value ) {
  content+="Key :<b>"+key +"</b>  Value :<b>"+value+"</b><br/>";
});

   $('#coin_value').html(content);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="article">
  <h1>Ripple</h1>
  <p id="coin_value">test</p>
  <p></p>
  <p><strong></strong></p>
</article>
```